# QTableView: Best way to change activation-trigger to double-click

Tags: qt

In my application, I have one tableview of items, and a side-panel "preview":ing the latest selected item.

I want clicking on an item to change the selection, and double-clicking to cause a "run"-action to be performed. More specifically, I want the "run"-action (including key-navigation and pressing enter) to be bound to the "activation" of the item in the table-row.

My problem is; single-clicks does not only change the selection, but fires the "activated" signal on the item. I would like to tweak it such that:

Navigation Keys, Single Mouse Click: Selection-change, update preview-panel
Enter Key, Double Mouse Click: Activate/run/open action triggered.

Is there a nice clean way to do it, or are overriding the onclick/doubleclick events my best option? Or is there some other tabular list-widget better suiting my needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would connect the slot for the preview action to the [currentChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) signal of the table view's selectionModel(). This covers single clicks and key navigation.

Then there's two options for the double clicks and Enter key presses:

1. Subclass your tableview, override doubleClickEvent() and keyPressEvent() and fire your custom signal in there, with maybe the model index or something else as an argument. Then just connect your run method to your own signal as you have full control over when it is fired.
2. If you don't want to subclass, you can use the [installEventFilter()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#installEventFilter) mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and helpful response. I realize I misinterpreted the role of the "activated" signal.

Answer (score 0):

Either I'm getting your approach wrong or I'm too tired, but if you want to trigger a run event you should avoid the activated signal completely. Set the signal slot mechanism so that your double click and Enter key press event trigger your run() function, and then the single click/nav buttons should trigger the 'activated' slot which will return your index in the tableview.

I'm pretty certain Qt wants you to be explicit about which signal points to which slot or it'll ignore it or point to a default.